# Structured Streaming 2.1.0 Foreach not called

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to test foreach of structured streaming with Kafka on a yarn cluster and have this little piece of code:

```
  val ds1 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "data01:9092,data02:9092,data03:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "cluster-topic-01")
  .load()


  /* This block works
  val query = ds1.writeStream
        .format("console")
        .start()
  */

  // this block doesn't have any call to open()
  val query = ds1.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
          override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
                println("open("+partitionId+","+version+")")
                true
          }

          override def process(record: Row) : Unit = {
            // write string to connection
                println("process() :: "+record)
          }

          override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
            // close the connection
                println("close()")
          }
  }).start()

  query.awaitTermination()
```

When I run this program, there is no call to open(). I have compared other examples from other threads but I can't find out what's missing. There is a start() call after foreach which seems to match what the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes).

I can stream to a file or a console but just can't get any call in foreach.

Any suggestion on where to look at? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

`open`, `process` and `close` will run in the executors like `RDD.foreach`, so you won't be able to see it unless you are using local mode.